# Android: Using Native Executable to capture screen only returns a partial screen

Tags: android, screen-capture

I'm using Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and have created a Native Executable (loaded separately using ADB) that uses the following code to grab the framebuffer:

```
std::string theMessage;
android::sp <android::IBinder> display = android::SurfaceComposerClient::getBuiltInDisplay(android::ISurfaceComposer::eDisplayIdMain);
android::ScreenshotClient ssc;
if (ssc.update(display) == android::NO_ERROR) {  // may also use ssc.update(displayID, width, height) to refine different resolutions
    theMessage = s_screenshot;
    theMessage += toStringPadTwo(ssc.getWidth());
    theMessage += toStringPadTwo(ssc.getHeight());
    uint32_t size   = ssc.getSize() ;
    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)(ssc.getPixels());
    for (int i=0; i<(size); i+=1) {
        theMessage += buffer[i];
    }
    std::cout << "TakeScreenshot returned with WIDTH = " << ssc.getWidth() << " and HEIGHT = " << ssc.getHeight() << std::endl;
    s_sysServerPtr->sendMessage(theMessage);  // return screen capture data to Java app
}
else {
    theMessage = s_fbFailed;
    s_sysServerPtr->sendMessage(theMessage); // return failed response to Java app
}
```

I'm testing this code on a Nexus 7 touchpad that has a screen resolution of 800x1280.  Each call to this snippet of code returns the correct number of bytes (800*1280*4).  However, each call only returns a portion of the screen, chopping off the top portion and filling the bottom remainder with black pixels.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Could it be an issue with device rotation, causing you to interchange the needed x and y dimensions?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, No, the device rotation is correctly returned 800x1280 or 1280x800.  The interesting part is each returned portion chops off from the top a seemingly random amount of the screen.